# How to serialize JSON Request data from serializer in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to serialize a json data through serializers.Serializer

```
{
    "data": {
        "phoneNumber": "1234567890",
        "countryCode": "+11",
        "otp": "73146",
    }
}
```

The sterilizer class I wrote for it

```
class VerifyOtpSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=225, source='phoneNumber', required=True)
    country_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=225, source='countryCode', required=True)
    otp = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
```

[image]

and also

I don't know why source is not working, I tried the JSON in the picture below but still it's saying the field is required

[image]

Comment: Can you try phone_number instead of phoneNumber.

Comment: `source` is not the key that will be passed for the field. `source` is the name of the field / attribute on the _model class_. Also see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` value is what the passed value's key will be changed into. So `source` value is expected to be on your `Model`.

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field.

What you really want is something that changes camel case payload into a snake case. Just use [djangorestframework-camel-case](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case) and remove `source` from your serializer fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your keys are wrong in the request. as Tom said the source should be an attribute of the model object. so you have to match keys in request and serializer

change `phoneNumber` > `phone_number`
change `countryCode` > `country_code`

Comment: I can't because app is in prod 

Comment: then change field name in your serilaizer to match with the JSON

Comment: yeah, it's the last option

Answer (score 0):

The response object you are are sending to your serializer is in correct. The key of your request object should be exactly what you have defined in your serializer.

Try sending this to your serializer.

```
{
    "data" : {
        "phone_number":"1234567890",
        "country_code":"+11", 
        "otp":"73146"
    }
}
```

Comment: but I can't alter the json data

Comment: If you can't change the JSON data and if you can't update the `serilizer` as it is in production, then perhaps there is nothing that you and the community could do fix the issue.